# ggplot2: legend of two different data sets

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am drawing a map with ggplot using a shape file. Then I add arcs using geom_line. The arcs are colored according to their type (oneway or twoway) and then I add nodes using geom_point. The nodes are colored according to their type (Origin, Destination, Node, Parking lot). I want to have two different legends: one for the node types and one for the arc types. Unfortunately, ggplot merges the legends and produces just one legend.

Here is the code (sorry that I can't provide a workable example. I can't send the shape files):

```
cityplot <- ggplot(data = s_zurich, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = id), fill = "white") +
            geom_polygon(data = s_zurich, fill = "white") + 
            ylab("") + xlab("") + 
            theme(axis.text.x = element_blank(), axis.text.y = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank())

cityplot_arcs <- cityplot + 
                 geom_line(data = allarcs, aes(x = X1, y = X2, group = Id, colour = Direction), size = 1) +
                 xlab("") + ylab("")

cityplot_arcs_nodes <- cityplot_arcs + geom_point(aes(x = lon, y = lat, colour = Type), shape = 15, size = 4, inherit.aes = FALSE, data = allnodes) + 
                       theme(legend.position = "none")
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Care to take your problem reproducible? We don't have access to your data.

Comment: Indeed, being able to work the code in our own session would help. I presume that you've read the [`guides`](http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/guides.html) help file? On the other hand, I do remember something that there can be only one colour scale (or legend, I am not sure) in a single ggplot.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible workaround. If you can keep your `geom_polygon` fill out of the `aes()` call - as looks to be the case above, then you can use a filled shape for the point (21 is a circle) and set the fill attribute rather than the color in the `aes()` call. See below:

```
mock_data<-
  data.frame(x=sample(1:10,20,T),
             y=sample(1:10,20,T),
             direction=sample(c("1way","2way"),20,T),
             type=sample(c("origin","destination","node","lot"),20,T))


ggplot(mock_data) +
  geom_polygon(aes(x=c(0,12,12,0),y=c(0,0,12,12),id=c(1,1,1,1)),fill="white") +
  geom_point(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=type),size=10,shape=21) + 
  geom_line(aes(x=x,y=y,color=direction),size=2) +
  scale_fill_brewer(palette="Greens") + scale_color_brewer(palette="Set1")
```

[image]

Failing that, you can plot a mock legend only using `ggplot()` and use `grid.arrange()` to plot it next to your graph minus the default legend. Let me know in the comments if you need help with that.